# Running php artisan ide:models automatically

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I create a command through make:command

```
php artisan make:command ResetDBCommand
```

Then I would like to run the two command in handler

```
php artisan ide:models
php artisan db:seed
```

However, it's not work for me to fire the two command automatically through the below codes

```
Artisan::call('db:seed');
$console->writeln('db:seed done.');

Artisan::call('ide:models--force');
$console->writeln('ide:models done.');
```

Error:

```
The command "ide:models--force" does not exist.
```

how can I do that?

Comment: usually there is a space between a command name and its arguments and options ... but also there is a syntax for calling commands with options

Comment: @lagbox I tried 'ide:models --force' before and I got this error - The command "ide:models" does not exist

Comment: does the command exist?

Comment: @lagbox this is not from php artisan. It comes from barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper. But also I need to trigger the update setting through console with the command - php artisan ide:models then input 'y'

Comment: Isn't the command `ide-helper:models` ?

Comment: @apokryfos I can manually finish the process by  'php artisan ide:models' console. However, I would like Laravel to do all the stuffs through make:command.

Comment: I'm just reading https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper it mentions `ide-helper:models` being the command. I was not aware that `ide:models` also works. Also are you running those commands in the `handle` method of your command?

Comment: @apokryfos If I manually input  'ide:models' it's not work, I need to input 'php artisan ide:models' .  Yes ~ I would like to execute two command through  'handle' . It works only if I run db:seed. When I add one more command (ide:models or php artisan ide:models), it will fail. I believe it's because this one need confirmation to trigger the process.

Comment: If you do only `Artisan::call('ide:models')` do you get  `The command "ide:models" does not exist` as well?

Comment: @apokryfos yes that's why I come up to ask for a help ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command is `ide-helper:models` you can confirm this if you do:

```
php artisan help ide:models
```

You get:

> [...]
> Usage:
> ide-helper:models [options] [--] [<model>...]

which indicates that Laravel does automatically resolve this command when called in the command line. However such resolution mechanism does not exist when calling it programmatically.

Another issue is that `--force` is not a valid option in `ide-helper:models` here's what you can do though:

```
Artisan::call('db:seed');
$console->writeln('db:seed done.');

// Uncomment one of the two
// Artisan::call('ide-helper:models --nowrite'); // Only write metadata in the _ide_helper_models.php file
// Artisan::call('ide-helper:models --write'); // Write metadata on models
// ------
$console->writeln('ide:models done.');
```

Pick whichever one you prefer accordingly

Tested the above in Laravel 8